# Failed to compile TypeScript single-ton using Babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

In TypeScript, Class has `private constructor()` , so we can create single-ton pattern classes easily like the following.

```
class Singleton {
  static instance = new Singleton();
  prop = 0;

  private constructor() {}
}

Singleton.instance.prop; // 0
```

When I build this TypeScript code using Babel without TSC, raising an error `Singleton is not a constructor` .
What should I do?

Comment: First question - why use babel when you have typescript? You can directly tell typescript to compile to i.e. ES5 javascript. Second - I am not using babel on regular basis, but I think process should be traspile typescript to javascript and then use babel...?

Comment: Check which TSC version is used (the command is `tsc --version` IIRC) **edit:** Also check if your editor is using the correct version too.

Comment: @libik I should use Babel because using a framework having dependency it...

Comment: @Seblor I use Babel as TypeScript transpiler instead of TSC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this as there is no other answer in couple of hours. I am not answering question directly, but it can be also the answer about the solution itself.

In Node.js world, it does not make sense to make extra singletons. Why? Every single file is singleton on its own.

If you have file (module) that looks like this:

```
class Singleton {
  constructor() {}
}

exports.instance = new Singleton();
```

Then you can only access the instance, that is basically singleton. There is really no way to access anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue.  Compiling your code (with a console.log around the last line), with this babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Yields the following code, which runs as expected:

```js
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }

var Singleton = function Singleton() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Singleton);

  _defineProperty(this, "prop", 0);
};

_defineProperty(Singleton, "instance", new Singleton());

console.log(Singleton.instance.prop); // 0
```